# libcudart on system without a GPU

Tags: linux, drivers, gpu

I have code which, based on the availability of GPUs, either runs a GPU kernel or the same code on the CPU. It does this at runtime and the program is always linked to CUDA.

However, I may want to run on computers that don't have *any* GPUs. We tried installing the CUDA Toolkit on the computer, but `libcudart` is missing. How do I get this?

Both the desktop machines (which have GPUs) and the grid machines (which don't) are running RHEL 6.7 and we used [literally] the same CUDA installer for both, but didn't select the driver on the grid (since there's no GPU and it would probably yell at us).

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you don't have a GPU? ix86 computers typically have a GPU built in to the CPU these days. Additionally, did the instructions at http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~mwb7w/cuda_support/libcudart.html help?

Comment: The grid nodes are rack-mounted devices purchased only for their CPUs and networking. The only VGA controller (as seen in `lspci -vv`) is an ASPEED Technology Inc. controller. Yes, I'm sure it has no CUDA-capable GPUs.

Comment: Ah. So it does have a GPU, it just doesn't have a CUDA-capable GPU.

Comment: Right, and that prevents the CUDA "driver" from installing.

Comment: Have you seen [this link](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/485245/running-a-cuda-application-on-a-gpu-less-machine/)?

Comment: I have now, which leads me to the question of how to coax CMake's `cuda_add_executable` to *not* link to `libcuda`

Comment: Or I can just copy `libcuda` itself. @AFH please turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @iAdjunct - I haven't tried it, and I have no easy way to do so; in addition, you have raised issues, so I am unwilling to submit an untested and incomplete suggestion as an answer. If you get it working, submit the answer yourself, because you will be able to give the complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the nvidia driver is unable to get access to an nvidia device or if there is no nvidia driver, the CUDA **Driver** installer will fail. Part of the CUDA Driver appears to be the collection of libraries (like `libcudart` and `libcuda`), which then don't get installed.

However, if you install the CUDA Driver on another computer and do

```
cp -r /usr/local/cuda/lib64/ /somewhere/else/cuda_libs
cp /usr/lib64/libcuda.so.1 /somewhere/else/cuda_libs/libcuda.so.1
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/somewhere/else/cuda_libs"
```

Then the other computer can use the cuda libraries. Obviously this doesn't magically create a device and you need to not try to use said nonexistent device, but at least your code that links against cuda will work.

I've tested this successfully between RHEL 6.7 systems, though I don't know just how ubiquitously this solution will work.